# Best way to render a route between two static meteor templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, iron-router

I have a {{> staticFooter}} template and a {{> staticHeader}} template. I was wondering if there exists a good way to render between these two templates for each page that I use iron:router to navigate to.

```
{{> staticHeader}}
   RENDER Iron:Router STUFF HERE
{{> staticFooter}}
```

Comment: http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a template that will serve as the layout for all of your pages.

```
<template name="MasterLayout">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Page wrapper -->
    <div id="page-wrapper"> 
        <!-- Header -->
        {{> staticHeader }}

        <!-- Main view  -->
        {{> yield}}

        <!-- Footer -->
        {{> staticFooter }}

    </div>
    <!-- End page wrapper-->

  </div>
  <!-- End wrapper-->
</template>
```

Configure your router to use this template as the default layout:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'MasterLayout'
});
```

Create templates for each of your pages:

```
<template name="Content">
  <div>
    <p>Render Iron:Router STUFF HERE</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Create a route for each page:

```
Router.route('/', function(){
   this.render('Content'); // Render the Content template into the 'main' yield region
});
```